# Rails - How are route helper methods named?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

When I run `rake routes` I get this:

```
person_name GET    /:id/person/:person_id/name(.:format)    persons#name
```

What would the "helper name" be for this route? I essentially want to be able to do something like this:

`redirect_to person_name_path`

## Edit

My routes.rb looks like this:

`get ':id/person/:person_id/name'       => 'person#name', as: :person_name`

Comment: Do you get an error when you try to redirect to that path?

Comment: Indeed, I get a "Template is Missing" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't a restful route, but you can create that route anyway if you wish like this:

```
match ':id/person/:person_id/name' => 'people#name', :via => :get, :as => 'person_name'
```

Of course you need the appropriate controller method and template to go with it.

Comment: Excuse my noobiness, but I edited my question - Is what you have here different than what I am already doing?

Comment: Yes, that should work also. And you need the controller method and template to match.

Comment: Ah, silly mistake...I didn't create the template, thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project!